# If else condition in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have an application where in index.cshtml file I am loading an external JavaScript file

```
<head>
<script scr="External Javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

Now the problem is I want to restrict the loading of the file for a few users.
How can I achieve it here?

Comment: Restrict based on what conditions?

Comment: you need to implement this flltering on your server side scripts

Comment: look into `roles`. so you can check if a user is in a `role`.

Comment: @RayonDabre Based on the extension (s)he uses ASP.NET

Comment: you should use only server side code to do this, doing it in html or client side code(javascript jquery or html) is not secure.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do this in pure JavaScript

```
 <script>
    if (condition) { //whatever that might be 
       document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='sourcepath.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
    }
 </script>
```

However there's nothing preventing a user from figuring out the script path (since it's just written there) and then loading it manually.

You'd want to make sure you don't use this method to hide content that only privileged users can see.